# Pay rise within the department

Tags: salary

If my boss is not giving any pay raises this year to the department, does he have to make a statement to everyone in the department?

Comment: Does he have to give a pay raise at all?

Comment: Is there a contract?  Is there a union?  Are there relevant local laws?  Does the company have any relevant policies?  We can't answer this as asked; it's too broad.

Answer (score 4):

No, you're boss doesn't *have* to say anything concerning salary changes. You should be able to privately ask your boss, though. Otherwise, I would expect to remain at the same salary until I hear otherwise.

Comment: This can depend heavily upon location.  For instance, in Australia there are industry-specific 'Award' contracts that specify the minimum rate of pay for various occupations.  These are reviewed annually and adjusted for cost-of-living increases.  In such a case, an employer is legally obliged to provide an appropriate pay increase.

Answer (score 0):

> Does my employer have to let me know there is no pay rise this year.

No. In the US at least, and assuming there is no contract to the contrary, employers are under no obligation to give a raise, nor to notify employees that there will be no raise this year.

> If my boss is not giving pay rise this year to the department does he
>   have to make a statement to everyone in the department.

No. There is no obligation to make any statement to anyone at all.